# extract with regex + if/else statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, extract

Is it possible to create a (def) function & extract specific values from 1 column(has 50 rows) and use regex with an if/else statement?

I need to extract the following strings as if/else statement

```
\d*\s*milliliter
\d*\s*liter
\d*\s*ounce
\d*\s*kilogram
\d*\s*fluid\s*ounce
```

It can be returned as 'None' if the match is not found

My code below is currently looking very simple with just the extract. But I am not be able to figure out how to code it in an else/if/return statement.

```
def extract_data(df):

    pattern = '(\d*\s*milliliter|\d*\s*liter|\d*\s*ounce|\d*\s*kilogram|\d*\s*fluid\s*ounce)'

    return df.str.extract(pattern)
```

The column name is "Unit"

Comment: You're not specifying the column to extract from.

Comment: Should be df. I have just edited it and specified the column to extract from

Comment: Where do you specify the column? It should be `df.Unit.str.extract(pattern)`

Comment: Why do you think you need an `if/else`? This will return a new dataframe containing the extracted data in each row.

Comment: My codes are always very simple and I have never really tried an if/else statement. I wanted to understand how I can apply this on my data.

Comment: you don't generally use `if/else` in pandas, unless you need to test an aggregate condition on the dataframe as a whole.

Comment: I meant you didn't specify the column in the code.

Comment: You should provide a dummy example of a DataFrame and the matching expected output for clarity. What you are trying to achieve is currently unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'Unit': {0: '\\d*\\s*milliliter', 1: '\\d*\\s*liter', 2: '\\d*\\s*ounce', 
                 3: '\\d*\\s*kilogram', 4: '\\d*\\s*fluid\\s*ounce', 5: '\\d*\\s*nanosecond'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
Unit
0   \d*\s*milliliter
1   \d*\s*liter
2   \d*\s*ounce
3   \d*\s*kilogram
4   \d*\s*fluid\s*ounce
5   \d*\s*nanosecond
```

---

**Code**

`str.extract` don need if/else for extract NaN when match is not.

```
pat = r'(\d*\s*milliliter|\d*\s*liter|\d*\s*ounce|\d*\s*kilogram|\d*\s*fluid\s*ounce)'
out = df['Unit'].str.extract(pat)
```

`out`

```
    0
0   milliliter
1   liter
2   ounce
3   kilogram
4   ounce
5   NaN
```

Comment: I doubt the input is a series of literal `\d*\s*milliliter`, those are most likely examples of the patterns to be matched. So a simple `\d*\s*(?:(?:milli)?liter|(?:fluid\s*)ounce|kilogram)` should work. Which is more or less what OP already suggested.

Comment: So I understand that  str.extract won’t need an if/else. But can I replace ‘str.extract by another operator/function so I can still apply if/else on the dataframe? I changed my mind for NaN. I want to return “Not found” if the match is not found.

Comment: then use `filna`. hard to know what you want, but you probably don't need if/else for what you want.